# Storing a large dictionary with non-unique key-value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a large (over a  million characters) text file of this shape:

```
'abc' 2
'nmb' 3
'sds' 5
'abc' 6
```

As you see, each line has two elements. The pairs on each line are not unique, meaning 'abc' could map to 2 and 3 and probably many more. I need to store this into a suitable data structure that I could save to a file. Later I would like to see for example how many times a string has showed up and how many times it has been mapped to a certain number. I need to be able to do this relatively quickly, otherwise I could just use the file as-is.

I first tried to create a dictionary and store the data using the `json` library, which was pretty easy and straightforward to do. But then I realized I can not use that because the key-value pairs are not unique and a key can be mapped to several values and the data structure should preserve that.

So given the largeness of the file and the way I want to use it, what is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a `dict` of `list`s?:

```
{ 
    'abc': [2, 6],
    'nmb': [3],
    'sds': [5]
}
```

Edit after further understanding the OP's use case: you could also do this:

```
{
    'abc': {2: 3, 6: 7},
    'nmb': {3: 1},
    'sds': {5: 1},
}
```

You can also use `defaultdict` and `collections.Counter` as mentioned by the other answers to shortcut out of doing some of the work.

Comment: This is good, but the problem is, I also need to keep an eye on how many times a certain key has appeared in the entire text and this way that information is lost.

Comment: @mu I fixed it. OP: I think the idea is that every time another `'abc'` line appears in the file, you append to the corresponding list, so the `len()` of that list tells you how many times the key appeared.

Comment: Not really. 'abc' might have been mapped to 2 three times and to 6 seven times and I'd still get a `len` of two. I need to have that information.

Comment: Then `'abc': [2, 6],` would actually be `'abc': [2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],`

Comment: Perhaps you should use a `collections.Counter` instead of a list inside the dictionary. That will count the occurrences of each integer.

Comment: @DanD. Ok, fair enough. This seems to be a good idea. I like its succinctness and lack of need for libraries. I am weighing this against `collection.Counter` now to see which one suits my constraints better.

Answer (score 3):

> how many times a string has showed up and how many times it has been mapped to a certain number.

If that's the specific problem you're trying to solve, I would try a dict mapping the strings to [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instances. You can then trivially look up by string key and then by numeric key (to get the "count" value) (`data['abc'][2]` -> `1`), or look up by string key and sum the values of the Counter to get a total number of occurrences (`sum(data['abc'].values())` -> `2`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
with open("input.txt", "rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split()
        data[key].append(value)
```

The advantage of the defaultdict is that you don't need to initialize an empty list for every new key that you encounter.

Finding out how many times a key appeared is a simple `len(data[key])` statement.

While saving this back, either [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html) it, or have a single entry for each key, with comma separated values in the file so that you can reconstruct it quickly later:

```
with open("output.txt", "wt") as f:
    for key in data:
        f.write("{} {}\n".format(key, ','.join(data[key])))
```